# Flash Builder Child Popup call Parent Function

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

I have a custom component that is created via as:

```
public function myFunc():void {
   //some code
}

public function createComp():void {
  var myVar:customComp = new customComp();
  myVar.button01.label = "Some label";
  PopUpManager.addPopUp(myVar, this, true);
}
```

When a button is pressed (button01) on that component, I want it to call the myFunc function on the parent component. Keep in mind that all of this is in as. Where do I add the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

FIOFM, from this reference: http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg86364.html

In PopUp, create a new function variable, then create a button handler function, like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        public var onSubmit:Function;

        public function buttonHandler():void {
            onSubmit.call();
        }
...
```

In parent, add a public function:

```
public function openCustComp():void
{
    var custComp:panelComp = new panelComp();
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(custComp, this, true);
    custComp.onSubmit = clearCISD;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(instSuppDiaAdd);
}
```